# Beanutils.clonebean(object) vs Beanutils.copyproperties(object1,object2)

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

Both can be used to create a copy of the object. I wanted to know which is more efficient when more number of copy objects needs to be created. which would be faster when used in loop.

Comment: Why didn't you try by yourself?

Comment: I tried both.currently, I am having 80 objects and both seem same at current condition. But the number of objects will increase 10 per week or so that's why I asked. UI loading depends on that bean method.